# unique substrings using suffix tree

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm, substring, suffix-tree

For a given string `S` of length `n`-

- Optimal algorithm for finding all unique substrings of `S` can't be less than `O(n^2)`. So, the best algorithm will give us the complexity of `O(n^2)`. As per what I have read, this can be implemented by creating suffix tree for `S`.

The suffix tree for S can be created in `O(n)` time. Now, my question is-

**How can we use the suffix tree for S to get all the unique substrings of `S` in `O(n^2)`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to read about suffix arrays: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array
This method is faster than suffix tree for getting substrings in string.

Comment: Can you just explain how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done optimally through tries. Add the strings to trie and traverse from root to node. Each root to node path will denote suffixes of a string. Take all the prefixes of these suffixes. These are the unique substrings.